# Plotly animation in R

Tags: r, animation, shiny, plotly

HI I have to draw a simple animation on a date series using plotly in r on a shiny application.

```
p_animate <- data() %>%
      plot_ly(x=~Date,y=~Total_Count, showlegend = F, frame = ~Date) %>% 
      add_lines(line=list(width=2), text = c(''), hoverinfo = 'text', showlegend = F) %>% 
      add_markers() %>%
      layout(
        annotations = list(x = 1.30, y = -0.1, text = "*Updates - Daily", 
                           showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
                           xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                           font=list(size=10, color="#c9c9c9")),
        title = list(text = paste0('Count'), 
                     font = plot_title_font_family,
                     x = plot_title_x_y[['x']],
                     y = plot_title_x_y[['y']],
                     xanchor= 'center',
                     yanchor= 'top'),
        autosize = T,
        xaxis = list(type = 'date', title = "", tickfont = plot_x_y_labels, showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = 0, showline = FALSE),
        yaxis = list(title = list(text = paste0('Count'), 
                                  font = plot_title_font_family), 
                     tickfont = plot_x_y_labels, showgrid = FALSE),
        showlegend = T
      )
```

data() - *this a reactive element*

Issues

1. Animation not working as expected; A continuous line graph with time is expected. (increasing count)
2. The date axis is displayed in a format *DateTime* whereas I only have dates of type(YYYY-MM-DD) in the column. It also starts from  1970 whereas my date starts from 2019.

Any help is appreciated.
Please before closing this, let me revert on it. Many times the question misunderstood mainly because it might be asked poorly. Cross question but don't close.

Comment: To make this reproducible would you be able to share limited data you are using for this? In particular, what you would be starting with from your reactive expression `data()`?

Comment: Sure, it's here
https://www.kaggle.com/shahrukh0603/data-for-plotly

Comment: @ShahRukhK it is better if you provide the code to remake the data with `dput`. Firstly, it is more convenient to have all the information in a unique place (your post) and secondly, the link to the page you refer to might be broken in the future.

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to use a `POSIXct` or `date` with `frame` argument in `plot_ly` - which might be problematic - see [github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1246). One way to get around this is to calculate number of days since the first day for an animation. Then your xaxis and frame would need to be set to that numeric value. I'm curious to know if other/betters solutions are available. Also, you might want to create a very simple/toy dataframe and 2 lines of code to make an example `plot_ly` animation with dates. Most code provided here may be unnecessary.

Comment: thanks @Ben will try

Comment: sure @bretauv .will do that